# Error in UseMethod("LRtest") : no applicable method for 'LRtest' applied to an object of class "data.frame"

Tags: r, spss

I want to do LRtest for an SPSS data imported to r. I wrote the following code:

```
data<-read.spss("C:/..../sp.sav",use.value.label=F, to.data.frame=T)

res<-PCM(data)

res1<-LRtest(res,se=T)
```

however, the following error don't let me continue my analysis.

```
Error in Use Method("lrtest") : 
  no applicable method for 'LRtest' applied to an object of class "data.frame"
```

Comment: Your first line of code is missing its closing quotation mark

Comment: @camille: Good catch. Given the nature of the error, though, I'm assuming that was a problem in how this was copied to Stack Overflow, and not the source of the error. Still should be confirmed by the author, of course, and fixed if it's incidental to the question.

Comment: yes: data<-read.spss("C:/..../sp.sav",use.value.label=F, to.data.frame=T)